# Overwrite text in EditText that has only 1 char is not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have multiple `EditText` views , each `EditText` view can contain only 1 char.
I need to make this rule - if I focus on one `EditText` , and it already has some text inside - then overwrite it . Also - if I press on delete key - I need the text to be cleared inside that view.

Then - I am checking if the `EditText` views has 1 empty cell - if not - checking if the `EditText` views has the correct letters.

I could have managed to make the clear button work, but I can not make the overwrite.

I did tried to use the `TextWatcher` , but it didn't work for me.
The `EditText` views are created **dynamically** .

*Here is my code :*

**Answer.java**

```
public class Answer {

    String answer;
    int answer_length;

    int cell_margin=10;
    int cell_size=180;
    EditText[] EditTextArray;

    public Answer(RelativeLayout rLayout1, Context context , String answer) {

        this.answer = answer;

        answer_length = answer.length();
        if (answer_length>6){
            cell_margin = 4;
            cell_size = 110;
        }
        EditTextArray = new EditText[answer_length];
        AnswerCell EditTextToSeeFirst = new AnswerCell(context,cell_size);
        setListener(EditTextToSeeFirst);
        EditTextArray[0] = EditTextToSeeFirst;


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        fparams.setMargins(cell_margin,0,cell_margin,0);
        rLayout1.addView(EditTextToSeeFirst, fparams);


        for (int i = 1; i<answer_length ; i++){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, EditTextArray[i-1].getId());
            lparams.setMargins(cell_margin,0,cell_margin,0);
            AnswerCell newEditText = new AnswerCell(context,cell_size);
            setListener(newEditText);
            EditTextArray[i] = newEditText;

            rLayout1.addView(EditTextArray[i], lparams);

        }
        rLayout1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER );
    }

    public void setListener(AnswerCell ac){
        ac.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.d("test","test");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                goToNextAvailableCell();
            }
        });

    }

    public  void goToNextAvailableCell(){
        for (int i = 0; i<answer_length ; i++) {
            if(EditTextArray[i].getText().toString().matches("")){
                EditTextArray[i].requestFocus();
                return;
            }
        }
        //Did not found empty cell
        checkCorrectAnswer();
    }

    private void checkCorrectAnswer(){
        String tryAnswer = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<answer_length ; i++) {
            tryAnswer += EditTextArray[i].getText().toString();
        }
        if (tryAnswer.matches(answer)){
            Log.d("Correct !!","Correct Answer");
        }

    }

}
```

**AnswerCell.java**

```
public class AnswerCell extends EditText{

    public AnswerCell(final Context context, int cell_size) {
        super(context);
        this.setId(View.generateViewId());
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.color.answerCellBackground);
        this.setHeight(cell_size);
        this.setWidth(cell_size);
        this.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
        this.setCursorVisible(false);
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        this.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){

            public void onFocusChange( View view, boolean hasfocus){
                if(hasfocus){
                    view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.answer_cell_has_focus);
                }
                else{
                    view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.answer_cell_lost_focus);
                }
            }
        });

        this.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                    ((EditText)v).setText("");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

}
```

thanks **!**

Answer (score 0):

It will work with this code

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //YOUR CODE
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //YOUR CODE
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          String outputedText = s.toString();
```

//      mOutputText.setText(outputedText);

```
        }
    };
```

Then add this in oncreate

```
  mInputText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        e2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        e3.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        e4.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Comment: I have the function public void setListener(AnswerCell ac) in Answer.java class , which add the listener. Do I need to put it in the AnswerCell.java class ? The problem is that it must to be in the Answer.java class in order to check if all other cells already has text..

Comment: no need for that. just save your EditText id's to process it further

Comment: but after I'm setting the text the watcher is called in infinity loop , no  ?

Comment: how you are setting text?

Comment: As you suggested  : mOutputText.setText(outputedText); . I'm wrong right  ?

Comment: No no, just in beforeTextChanged clear your text and dont do anything after it and let me know if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124269/discussion-between-mojo-and-rahul-khurana).